# Sublime Text 3 and sublime-grunt-build

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, sublimetext3, grunt-contrib-concat, grunt-contrib-less

So i have an error, while i try to build, there is commandline which says:

```
grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface. (v0.1.13)
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 99]
[cmd: ['grunt.cmd', '--no-color']]
[dir: F:\LavkaLavka\Shop]
[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\PROGRA~1\SOFTWARE\System\DISKEE~1\;C:\Program Files (x86)\SOFTWARE\Players\Quick time\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\SOFTWARE\Design\NodeJS\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files\SOFTWARE\Coders\MP4BOX;C:\Users\133\AppData\Roaming\npm]
```

So i have installed node.js with npm, then installed globally:
grunt
less
grunt-cli
grunt-less
grunt-contrib-concat
grunt-contrib-less

Then in sublime i've unpacked latest zip of ssublime-grunt-build here:
C:\Users\133\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\sublime-grunt-build

I have simple Sublime text 3 project file in core project folder with only this base folder:

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "settings":
    {
        "build_on_save": 1
    }
}
```

with package.json:

```
{
    "name": "133",
    "description": "This is only a test.",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "keywords": [
        "css",
        "less",
        "mobile-first",
        "responsive",
        "front-end",
        "framework",
        "web"
    ],
    "author": "133",
    "devDependencies": {
        "grunt": "~0.4.5",
        "grunt-cli": "~0.1.13",
        "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.5.1",
        "grunt-contrib-less": "~1.0.0",
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "~0.12"
    }
}
```

and Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    "use strict";

    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({

        // Metadata.
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        banner: '/*!\n' +
                ' * 133 v<%= pkg.version %>\n' +
                ' */\n',

        // Task configuration.
        concat: {
            options: {
                banner: '<%= banner %>',
                stripBanners: false
            },
            dist: {
                src: [
                    'js/133/transition.js',
                    'js/133/alert.js',
                    'js/133/button.js',
                    'js/133/carousel.js',
                    'js/133/collapse.js',
                    'js/133/dropdown.js',
                    'js/133/modal.js',
                    'js/133/tooltip.js',
                    'js/133/popover.js',
                    'js/133/scrollspy.js',
                    'js/133/tab.js',
                    'js/133/affix.js'
                ],
                dest: 'js/133.js'
            },
        },
        less: {
            compileCore: {
                options: {
                    strictMath: true
                },
                src: 'css/style.less',
                dest: 'css/style.css'
            }
        },
    });

    // These plugins provide necessary tasks.
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat', 'less']);

};
```

I've used Bootstrap 3 js files for test purpose
What am i missing?

I couldn't successfully google for grunt-cli exit code 99
and there are no official info on that i suppose...

Please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems that i missed point of installing grunt locally via cd to my directory and then: install grunt..Is there any way of using global grunt and plugin files, wihtout installing to local directory? It could be more handy in my case)